# Not typical miltimonitor xorg.conf - 2 GPUs (nvidia) and 5 Monitors

Tags: nvidia, graphics, xorg, multiple-monitors, elementary

I installed some time ago elementary OS Freya. I'm fighting for a couple of days to get the correct configuration for my not typical multimonitor set

2 nvidia graphics cards GeForce GTX 660 Ti & GeForce 9800 GT

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK104 [GeForce GTX 660 Ti] (rev a1)
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation G92 [GeForce 9800 GT] (rev a2)
```

5 monitors: DELL 2407WFP (portrait), HP LP2465 (portrait) on the left, Samsung SyncMaster 305T (landscape) in the center, HP LP2465 (portrait), HP LP2465 (portrait) on the right. 2 from left and center one are connected to GeForce GTX 660 Ti, two on the right are connected to GeForce 9800 GT.

```
Number of GPUs: 2

GPU #0:
  Name      : GeForce GTX 660 Ti
  UUID      : GPU-7e349abd-3c84-3a78-a48d-a67e440523c5
  PCI BusID : PCI:1:0:0

  Number of Display Devices: 3

  Display Device 0 (DFP-0):
      EDID Name             : Samsung SyncMaster
      Minimum HorizSync     : 49.306 kHz
      Maximum HorizSync     : 98.529 kHz
      Minimum VertRefresh   : 59 Hz
      Maximum VertRefresh   : 59 Hz
      Maximum PixelClock    : 268.000 MHz
      Maximum Width         : 2560 pixels
      Maximum Height        : 1600 pixels
      Physical Width        : 640 mm
      Physical Height       : 400 mm

  Display Device 1 (DFP-1):
      EDID Name             : DELL 2407WFP
      Minimum HorizSync     : 30.000 kHz
      Maximum HorizSync     : 83.000 kHz
      Minimum VertRefresh   : 56 Hz
      Maximum VertRefresh   : 76 Hz
      Maximum PixelClock    : 170.000 MHz
      Maximum Width         : 1920 pixels
      Maximum Height        : 1200 pixels
      Preferred Width       : 1920 pixels
      Preferred Height      : 1200 pixels
      Preferred VertRefresh : 60 Hz
      Physical Width        : 520 mm
      Physical Height       : 330 mm

  Display Device 2 (DFP-3):
      EDID Name             : HP LP2465
      Minimum HorizSync     : 30.000 kHz
      Maximum HorizSync     : 94.000 kHz
      Minimum VertRefresh   : 48 Hz
      Maximum VertRefresh   : 85 Hz
      Maximum PixelClock    : 193.250 MHz
      Maximum Width         : 1920 pixels
      Maximum Height        : 1200 pixels
      Preferred Width       : 1920 pixels
      Preferred Height      : 1200 pixels
      Preferred VertRefresh : 60 Hz
      Physical Width        : 520 mm
      Physical Height       : 330 mm


GPU #1:
  Name      : GeForce 9800 GT
  UUID      : GPU-85c402d2-ade0-7b69-3106-511d3995b152
  PCI BusID : PCI:2:0:0

  Number of Display Devices: 2

  Display Device 0 (DFP-0):
      EDID Name             : HP LP2465
      Minimum HorizSync     : 30.000 kHz
      Maximum HorizSync     : 94.000 kHz
      Minimum VertRefresh   : 48 Hz
      Maximum VertRefresh   : 85 Hz
      Maximum PixelClock    : 193.250 MHz
      Maximum Width         : 1920 pixels
      Maximum Height        : 1200 pixels
      Preferred Width       : 1920 pixels
      Preferred Height      : 1200 pixels
      Preferred VertRefresh : 60 Hz
      Physical Width        : 520 mm
      Physical Height       : 330 mm

  Display Device 1 (DFP-1):
      EDID Name             : HP LP2465
      Minimum HorizSync     : 30.000 kHz
      Maximum HorizSync     : 94.000 kHz
      Minimum VertRefresh   : 48 Hz
      Maximum VertRefresh   : 85 Hz
      Maximum PixelClock    : 193.250 MHz
      Maximum Width         : 1920 pixels
      Maximum Height        : 1200 pixels
      Preferred Width       : 1920 pixels
      Preferred Height      : 1200 pixels
      Preferred VertRefresh : 60 Hz
      Physical Width        : 520 mm
      Physical Height       : 330 mm
```

On nvidia autoconf only monitors on the left and center one are ok but two on the right are dark ... I can move cursor on them but nothin more. I realized that in this way I get nothing.

Right now I'm working on xorg.conf for this setup. I was looking for a similar configuration and came across [this one](http://www.sysxperts.com/general-tips/linux/linux-mint-with-nvidia-quad-monitor). I use it a little as bit to make mine but I'm not sure if it is ok. I would greatly appreciate it if you kindly give me some hand with this configuration.

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "Layout0"
    Identifier "Layout0"
    Screen 0 "Screen3" 0 0
    Screen 1 "Screen1" LeftOf "Screen3"
    Screen 2 "Screen4" RightOf "Screen3"
    InputDevice "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device1"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 660 Ti"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device2"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 660 Ti"
    Option         "Rotate" "left"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device3"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce 9800 GT"
    Option         "Rotate" "left"
    BusID          "PCI:2:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
  Identifier     "Monitor1"
  ModelName      "DELL 2407WFP"
  HorizSync       30.0 - 94.0
  VertRefresh     48.0 - 85.0
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
  Identifier     "Monitor2"
    ModelName      "HP LP2465"
  HorizSync       30.0 - 94.0
  VertRefresh     48.0 - 85.0
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor3"
    ModelName      "Samsung SyncMaster"
  HorizSync       49.0 - 98.0
  VertRefresh     59.0
  Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
  Identifier     "Monitor4"
    ModelName      "HP LP2465"
  HorizSync       30.0 - 94.0
  VertRefresh     48.0 - 85.0
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
  Identifier     "Monitor5"
    ModelName      "HP LP2465"
  HorizSync       30.0 - 94.0
  VertRefresh     48.0 - 85.0
EndSection

Section "Screen"
        Identifier      "Screen1"
        Device          "Device2"
        Monitor         "Monitor1"
        DefaultDepth    24
        Option          "SLI" "Mosaic"
        Option          "Stereo" "0"
        Option          "BaseMosaic" "True"
        Option          "MetaModes" "GPU-0.DFP-1: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
        SubSection      "Display"
        Depth           24
        EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
        Identifier      "Screen2"
        Device          "Device2"
        Monitor         "Monitor2"
        DefaultDepth    24
        Option          "SLI" "Mosaic"
        Option          "BaseMosaic" "True"
        Option          "MetaModes" "GPU-0.DFP-3: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
        SubSection      "Display"
        Depth           24
        EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
        Identifier      "Screen3"
        Device          "Device0"
        Monitor         "Monitor3"
        DefaultDepth    24
        Option          "SLI" "Mosaic"
        Option          "BaseMosaic" "True"
        Option          "MetaModes" "GPU-0.DFP-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
        SubSection      "Display"
        Depth           24
        EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
        Identifier      "Screen4"
        Device          "Device3"
        Monitor         "Monitor4"
        DefaultDepth    24
        Option          "SLI" "Mosaic"
        Option          "BaseMosaic" "True"
        Option          "MetaModes" "GPU-1.DFP-1: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
        SubSection      "Display"
        Depth           24
        EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
        Identifier      "Screen5"
        Device          "Device3"
        Monitor         "Monitor5"
        DefaultDepth    24
        Option          "SLI" "Mosaic"
        Option          "BaseMosaic" "True"
        Option          "MetaModes" "GPU-1.DFP-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
        SubSection      "Display"
        Depth           24
        EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Answer (score 0):

Nvidia has a application note describing using (2) Quadro cards with 4 displays. I have a working setup with a single quadro and 4 displays, using the MetaModes only option.

```
Option         "MetaModes" "1920x1080 +0+0, 1920x1080 +1920+0, 1920x1080 +0+1080, 1920x1080 +1920+1080"
```

http://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3580/~/how-to-configure-mosaic-on-linux